# Kibana - unknown configuration key deprecation.skip_deprecated_settings

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elk

I have an instance of Kibana which was not installed via RPM or DEB package.
Whole application was started via script and now I wanted to add it to systemd.
I am facing this error when I am trying to start kibana via systemd and I can't find any solution for that.

```
FATAL  Error: Unknown configuration key(s): "deprecation.skip_deprecated_settings". Check for spelling errors and ensure that expected plugins are installed
```

There is no such configuration key in my config.
Also not in elasticsearch configs.

```
server.basePath: "/kibana"
server.rewriteBasePath: true
server.name: "ELK Kibana"
elasticsearch.hosts: [ "https://10.10.10.10:9200", "https://10.10.10.11:9200", "https://10.10.10.12:9200", "https://10.10.10.13:9200" ]

xpack.security.enabled: true

server.ssl.enabled: true
server.ssl.certificate: "/opt/elk/kibana/config/ssl/kibana.crt"
server.ssl.key: "/opt/elk/kibana/config/ssl/kibana.key"

elasticsearch.ssl.certificate: "/opt/elk/kibana/config/ssl/kibana.crt"
elasticsearch.ssl.key: "/opt/elk/kibana/config/ssl/kibana.key"

elasticsearch.ssl.certificateAuthorities: [ "/opt/elk/kibana/config/ssl/elasticsearch-ca.pem" ]

elasticsearch.ssl.verificationMode: full

elasticsearch.requestTimeout: 60000
```

Has anyone faced an issue like this? I can't figure out what's wrong here.
Permissions are fine.

Comment: The `deprecation.skip_deprecated_settings` setting is an ES setting, so you should find it in `elasticsearch.yml`

Comment: @Val it is not present there

Comment: What do you get by running `curl -XGET https://10.10.10.10:9200/_nodes?filter_path=**.skip_deprecated_settings`

Comment: it returns me nothng: `{ }`

Comment: Any other ideas? :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you write that unit file yourself? If not please look at parameters with which Kibana is starting. Try to find the string:

> ExecStart=/usr/share/kibana/bin/kibana --logging.dest="/var/log/kibana/kibana.log" --pid.file="/run/kibana/kibana.pid" --deprecation.skip_deprecated_settings[0]="logging.dest"

As you can see, there is parameter `--deprecation.skip_deprecated_settings[0]="logging.dest"`
Try to remove it and don't forget to do `systemctl daemon-reload` before start service